# Changing tags dynamically

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kubernetes, fluentd

My goal is to be able to change log tags based on their content, and then dump them to a special, non-default index in elastic (the default index name is `logstash-%date%`).
I use the `https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch` plugin in order to be able to dump logs to elastic ([with the following default configmap](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch/fluentd-es-configmap.yaml)).

However, I will try to summarize the relevant parts of the config so a person which is not familiar with kubernetes but also with vanilla fluentd will be able to understand.

Here is the config file:

```
<source>
  tags all pods logs with "kubernetes.*" tag
</source>

<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type grep
  <regex>
    key name
    pattern ^bi$
  </regex>
</filter>

<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
    tag bi
  </record>
</filter>

<match bi>
  @type elasticsearch
  host ...
  port ...
  index_name bi
</match>
```

What I'm trying to do here, is first filter all logs tagged with "kubernetes.**", and check if their "name" field contains "bi" (throwed from my app).
Then, the next filter should change the tag to "bi" for logs that matched the previous filter.
Finally, I try to catch the logs tagged with "bi" and dump them to a special index named "bi".

However, the configuration doesn't manage to change the log tags.

Comment: Can you paste in the JSON that logstash is seeing, rather than the config of an upstream tool?

Comment: Do you mean the JSON elastic is seeing? There's no Logstash in my architecture, just Fluentd

Comment: Sorry - how about what a document looks like in ES then?